# External Display (HDMI) Not Working After 22.04 update

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I was using Ubuntu 22.04 fine some 30 minutes back. There was an `Update` prompt which I accepted, it asked for a restart when finished. But after that, my Samsung External monitor through HDMI is not detected. I do not see anything in `Settings` as well.

I tried the Windows 10 dual boot and the external monitor works fine.

Is there anything I can do to bring the external monitor back to life? Thanks

Edit 1 :

I switched from `Using Nvidia Driver Server.... 510' to

[image: `Using X.Org X server - Nouveau]

Now it detects, but it is mostly white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the `525 proprietary version` through `Additional Drivers`. It works fine for now.

PS: Not the `open, tested version`